# Best way to find the numeric value in UNIX file system

Tags: linux, unix

I need to grep for a particular port number from a huge set of files.

I am using a command:

```
find . |xargs grep "9461"
```

But it does not finds all the occurrences for number 9461.
Can anyone suggest a better unix/linux command to do so.

The kind of files it gets is : `x.log`, `y.txt`,`z.htm`, `a.out` etc files
But it was not able to get `abc.conf` files

Comment: Post the kind of files that it matches, and those that should be matched but aren't.

Comment: The kind of files it gets is : x.log, y.txt,z.htm, a.out etc files But it was not able to grep in abc.conf files

Comment: What do you mean with "it was not able to grep n ab.conf files"? That there was some 9461 in abc.conf but wasn't shown? Use `grep -H` to be sure it prints the filename it is grepping.

Answer (score 1):

You surely have some reason for using `find` in combination with `grep`, but just in case:

You can replace your command by:

```
grep -r "9461" .
```

and if you want even line numbers

```
grep -rn "9461" .
```

As JonathanLefflero commented, there is also the option **-e** that make grep match againt a regular expression, so, the ultimate command would be

```
grep -rne 9461
```

You should take a look on [grep man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep)

A final note, you should check if what you want to grep is `"9461"` or `9461` without `""`.

Comment: This can mean searching files multiple times as `find` lists the files and the parent directories, and the `grep -r` scans everything too. Using `grep -r -e 9461 .` might make sense.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, you're right!! Editing right now.